# Can I create repository in Bitbucket which is saved in github

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket

My purpose is to create a repository in github via bitbucket so that I can have private repository. Probably it's a stupid question but is it possible?

Comment: What goal do you try to achieve with this? Or let's say, what is it you can't do with a simple bitbucket (or github) repo? The stated need for both seems strange without additional details... Why want to *save* something which is, by definition, *actually* saved.

Comment: This way I can have free private repo as well as access to all the existing public repositories on github which is more in numbers as compared to bitbucket

Comment: "as well as access to all the existing public repositories on github"—What do you mean by "access"? These aren't closed ecosystems. There's nothing stopping you from using code from GitHub and code from Bitbucket (or GitLab, or any other Git provider) alongside one another.

Answer (score 0):

Well... what `github` and `bitbucket` are, is hosting services for `git` repositories.  If you create a repo in bitbucket, it will be available through bitbucket.  If you create a repo in github, it will be available through github.  You can consult each service's docs for info on what access models they support.

You can rig up links between repos hosted on the different services, but each one will (1) still have and use its own copy of the repo, and (2) provide access to said copy in accordance with how you've configured that service's access for that repo.